# Sending a packet to Telegram Bot's Web App View

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Telegram introduced Bot [Web App View](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps) recently, and I need from my bot, which is running in Python, to send a custom payload of data to the site. I know that the site can get stuff like color schemes, user info and so on, but I need my custom packet as well. I really need to use the web app as just an interface to a really, really small database (~30 items) in json. (Other solutions, like storing the database with the website is not useful nor convenient to me)

Is this even possible? I've tried looking everywhere, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Please be sure to read the TG docs on WebApps: https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#implementing-web-apps

Comment: @CallMeStag I have read them and I launched my WebApp, but I'm not sure, if I can customize the data that telegram will send to the WebApp in python

Answer (score 1):

ofcourse you can, it depends on the webapp you write, following python telegram bot manual i can use my webapp to send payload Json data for my bot.I used javascript in my webapp. for example
**1. code in my webapp**:

```html
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-web-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@jaames/iro@5"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" defer>
    Telegram.WebApp.ready();
    Telegram.WebApp.MainButton.setText('Xác nhận').show().onClick(function () {
        const data = JSON.stringify({
          username: document.querySelector('input[name=username]').value,
          password: document.querySelector('input[name=password]').value,
          date_start: document.querySelector('input[name=dates]').value,
          date_end: document.querySelector('input[name=datee]').value,
          ei_type: document.getElementsByName('ei_type')[0].value,
          download_ei: [].filter.call(document.getElementsByName('download_ei'), (c) => c.checked).map(c => c.value)
         });
        Telegram.WebApp.sendData(data);
        Telegram.WebApp.close();
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Telegram.WebApp.expand();
</script>
</body>
```

**2. my Python code:**

```py
# the async function where show up button press and open my webapp
async def downloadEI(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    user = update.callback_query.from_user
    usertelid = user.id
    msg_id = update.callback_query.message.message_id
    userFname = user.first_name
    userLname = user.last_name
    telusername = user.username

    if userFname is None:
        userFname = ""
    if userLname is None:
        userLname = ""
    if telusername is None:
        telusername = ""
    if userFname == "" or userLname == "":
        userFullname = telusername
    else:
        userFullname = userFname + " " + userLname

    query = update.callback_query
    logger.info("merLoadImgTop-User %s choose: %s", userFullname, str(query.data))

    await query.edit_message_text(f"@{telusername} processing your request...")

    # sleep(3)
    await update.callback_query.message.reply_text(
        "press me!",
        reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardMarkup.from_button(
            KeyboardButton(
                text="fill the info", web_app=WebAppInfo(url="my webapp url")
            ),
        ),
    )
    return DOWNLOADEIPROCESS


# the function when catching webapp return data:
async def downloadEIProcess(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    data = update.effective_message.web_app_data.data
```

please give more imformation about your code in order to let me help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Custom data cannot be currently transmitted from the bot to the webapp as of April 2022.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are needing this yet, but I found a way to do the comunication in bot -> webapp. It's the simpler way: with GET params :)

You just need to pass the data you want to 'post' to the webapp into a function that converts, in my case, a JSON object format into an HTTP URL parameters. Like this:

```
from urllib.parse import quote as urlparse
def dict_to_url_params(params: dict):
    # escape characters that are not allowed in url
    # example: {'name': 'John Doe?'} -> 'name=John%20Doe%3F'
    return "?" + '&'.join([f'{ urlparse(key) }={ urlparse(value) }' for key, value in params.items()])
```

Then, catch this data in JS, make what you want to, and with a press of a button call a function like this:

```
let params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
let name = params.get("name")
let age = params.get("age")
```

And to get this data in bot, do this:

```
import json
@bot.message_handler(content_types="web_app_data")
def answer(wmsg):
    userid = wmsg.from_user.id
    try:
        response = json.loads(wmsg.web_app_data.data)
    except:
        pass
```

This is a repository of a real example:
https://github.com/arthurrogado/WebApp-Telegram-Bot